# C# equivalent to Java SSL-socket-connection

Tags: c#, java, ssl, cisco

Hey guys I'm trying to write an AXL-client (SOAP) for the Cisco Unified Communications Manager. For that purpose I need to establish an ssl-connection to the AXL-service. Unfortunatly I dont know much about all that ssl-stuff.

However I was able to find a working Java-example, that does, what I want. The problem is, i need that in C#.NET. So I'm hoping, that someone could "translate" the following Java-code in a C#-version. But it has to do exactly the same, espacially the authentication and certificate-stuff.

Here is the code:

```
    String sAXLSOAPRequest = "...";
    byte[] bArray = null; // buffer for reading response from
    Socket socket = null; // socket to AXL server
    OutputStream out = null; // output stream to server
    InputStream in = null; // input stream from server

    X509TrustManager xtm = new MyTrustManager();
    TrustManager[] mytm = { xtm };
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    ctx.init(null, mytm, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sslFact = (SSLSocketFactory) ctx.getSocketFactory();

    socket = (SSLSocket) sslFact.createSocket("192.168.1.100", Integer.parseInt("8443"));
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    // send the request to the server
    // read the response from the server
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2048);
    bArray = new byte[2048];
    int ch = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    out = socket.getOutputStream();
    out.write(sAXLSOAPRequest.getBytes());

    while ((ch = in.read(bArray)) != -1) {
        sum += ch;
        sb.append(new String(bArray, 0, ch));
    }
    socket.close();
    // output the response to the standard output
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

and this is the MyTrustManager-Class:

```
public class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
MyTrustManager() {
    // create/load keystore
}

public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate chain[], String authType)
        throws CertificateException {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate chain[], String authType)
        throws CertificateException {
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

edit: sorry i should have mentioned: youre right i can generate a proxy-class, but sadly its not working properly. cisco did a really bad job with that (not to mention the really bad documentation). the proxy class throws some xml-errors when parsing some responses. so i have to do it manually for that cases...

i'll worry about the certificate security later

Comment: If I'm reading that code correctly, it doesn't actually check the validity of the certificates in question, providing near zero security value. I wouldn't bother with _that_ code any more, instead find a good C# TLS tutorial or API reference and go from there...

Comment: I don't know C# and .net, but you shouldn't have to go so low level. There should be some kind of Web Services / SOAP library that you can use, that will take care of the connection details, given the URL. Typically, you use a tool to parse the WSDL file for the SOAP service, and that writes all the code to access the service and encode/decode the data. For example, [check out this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100458/soap-client-in-net-references-or-examples)

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned: youre right i can generate a proxy-class, but sadly its not working properly. cisco did a really bad job with that (not to mention the really bad documentation). the proxy class throws some xml-errors when parsing some responses. so i have to do it manually for that cases...

Comment: There's no handy built-in SSL class in .NET. You can use SSLSocket class in our SecureBlackbox product (see http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php for details) which has the API similar to .NET Socket class and provides transparent SSL/TLS support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried consuming the web service the "proper" way?  Add a SOAP web service reference to your C# project in Visual Studio, gets the stubs etc?  That's the easiest way of doing it from C#.  You can just specify a https protocol in the URL when you add the reference.

Comment: That is not the same as using the wsdl, is it? How would I do that? Could you tell me how to start trying this, or are there some good sources you could recommend?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as using WSDL.  You add a web reference to your project and enter URL of the WSDL.  It generates classes that you can use in your project.