# adding wsdl to .net website doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, wsdl

I am trying to add a web service reference to my customer's windows server. I can add it by clicking the `Add Service Reference` from the menu and type the correct web service url in the address bar. Then I click the `GO` button to validate the url. It locates the web service perfectly. Then I click the `OK` button to finish the job.

Then I see that Visual Studio creates a folder called `App_WebReference`, and puts a file like this `Reference.svcmap` in that folder.

When I go to the c# code, I am trying to call the web service but I cannot reach it. However this work if I create a local project and do the same things I explained above.

Here is web service [url](https://yonetim-test.ziraatbank.com.tr/Innova.RegisterTransaction/RegisterTransaction.asmx) if you want to take a look at it. What am I doing wrong? I don't have any code to display because I couldn't code anything since I cannot reach the web service from c#. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should note the namespace when add the Serv reference. And then use that.

Comment: Can you explain _"When I go to the c# code, I am trying to call the webservice but I cannot reach it. However this work if I create a local project and do the same things I explained above."_ a bit more? What is "cannot reach it"? Do you get an error? What is "go to the C# code"? What is the difference between the two projects? How do you _use_ the generated code?

Comment: @henk-holterman I named the reference "ziraat". in aspx.cs file, I type "ziraat.savetransation()", intellisense doesnt work and it cannot  see the "ziraat". I do the same procedures in local project, it works

Comment: The term "cannot reach" is usually used in a different way when talking about services (as in: the service is unreachable), but it seems you cannot find the namespace in which the service client is generated. In that case [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100458/soap-client-in-net-references-or-examples) looks relevant.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. sorry about the English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added your Service Reference you gave it the **Namespace** of `ziraat` so the following code should access the method you are trying to call:

```
using (var client = new ziraat.RegisterTransactionSoapClient())
{
    client.SaveTransaction(...);
}
```

In addition I have seen an issue in Visual Studio where the Service Reference is added but the code generated is incorrect... This might be your issue?! To try a work-around:

- Right-click on the `ziraat` service reference item in your Solution Explorer tree
- Click **Configure Service Reference...** from the context-menu that appears
- Make sure that the **Reuse types in referenced assemblies** check box is **NOT** ticked
- Click **OK** to save the changes

Then try the code sample above again.