# How do I create a Soap Client in WebMatrix

Tags: php, .net, soap, webmatrix

I am trying to connect to a web service using .net.

I have a "Blueprint" for this. However it is in PHP. I want to do this using .net and basically i do not have Visual Studio. I am running running WebMatrix.

I checked the ASP.Net forums and I got this answer there

> *"WebMatrix doesn't provide any tooling for managing Web References. Open the Razor web pages site in Visual Studio and use that instead".*

I got this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100458/soap-client-in-net-references-or-examples)
from SO which is brilliant but does not serve my purpose and I cannot install Visual Studio on my system. I have to find a work around with Web Matrix.

HERE is the PHP CODE

```
<?php


//1. Include soap library
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

//2. instantiate soapclient class with the url of the soap server 
$client = new nusoap_client("URL for wsdl");

//3. Make a call to the web service
//the parameters to the Web Service must be encapsulated in an array in which the keys are the names defined for the service
$result = $client->call("Parameters to the Web Service));

//Display your result
echo "the latitude is ".$result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use Visual Studio Express for Web which is free (requires registration) to add the relevant service references and generate the proxy client, there is a command line tool called [SvcUtil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) that you can use to generate the required code for you.