# SOAP client in .NET referencing existing WSDL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've already read this useful thread about [SOAP and WSDL in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100458/soap-client-in-net-references-or-examples)

I'm trying to build a C# SOAP client, I've followed the instructions and added a "service reference" to the WSDL, but the client side proxy that is supposed to be generated, is **not** generated. I can only see classes, interfaces, enums, etc... I can't declare anything. I just can't:

```
MyService.MyWebServiceSoapClient ws = new MyService.MyWebServiceSoapClient();
```

Because I have no client to initialize.

So I tried to open a developer console and type

```
wsdl.exe <url_to_my_wsdl>
```

but it returned an error I can't understand. Something along the line:

> Impossible to import operation 'someOperation'.
>   Element parameters, belonging to the namespace urn:my:namespace, imported in 2 differents context: PrimitiveMapping, MembersMapping.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem by myself. After lots of trial and error modifications I came to the conclusion that the word "parameters" is not very welcome into .NET environment. So I changed it with "params" and now it is correctly imported by wsdl.exe

So part of my previous WSDL was something like:

```
<wsdl:message name="isServiceOnline">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="MyElement"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

The new version of it is:

```
<wsdl:message name="isServiceOnline">
    <wsdl:part name="params" element="MyElement"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```