# How to consume WSDL in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, wsdl

I was referred to this WSDL address: 
http://uhmistrn.doh.gov.ph/ahsr/webservice/index.php?wsdl

and it only shows PHP samples
http://uhmistrn.doh.gov.ph/ahsr/webservice/index.php

Pardon me for being a novice but this is my first encounter with WSDL.

Anyway, my point is, I need to consume this service to a Visual Basic-Web Application in Visual Studio 2012.
Can anyone show me how? Or to at least try how to use the authenticationTest method?

Comment: this will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100458/soap-client-in-net-references-or-examples

Comment: I already did adding the Service Reference but when I tried using these codes:
 
Dim client As New DohService.Online_Health_Facility_Statistical_Report_SystemPortTypeClient
 Dim result As String = client.authenticationTest("DOHTRAINING", "123456")
 Me.TextBox1.Text = result

It returns an error:

The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)....: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmls...

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: i think you need to change the encoding in app.config that i am not good in so cant help

Comment: try searching for basicHttpBinding encoding also let me know if you found a good solution it will help me as well

Comment: found this site last week, https://pathfindertech.net/connecting-to-a-php-web-service-with-wcf-in-c/. It's on C# and it works. Since I can't find any VB sample, so I just converted from VB to C#, =D