# Sending xml i am getting error 415 unsopported media type

Tags: c#, soap, httpclient

I need to make a soap request. For this work i am using http client.
I think that in soap request i need to set uri and action. Till now i am getting error code status 415. Unsupported media type. The problem is that i am not sending an action? And how can i send it if i use http client?

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");


var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2", new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"));
var answer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

If i will try to send same xml is been sending without any error.
So i believe that i need to send something more except my xml.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAPGv.jpg)

Inside the Raw it seems that i need to send action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6634420/2716623 - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I think the issue is with the credentials.  The server doesn't want a username and password in the xml.  Instead pass credentials like following example : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad5ee8ed-0af0-422b-b960-3ee7e40a4bbb/pass-in-credentials-for-basic-authentication?forum=wcf

Comment: @jdweng No, an HTTP 401 or 403 would indicate the credentials were invalid. Seriously, if you don't absolutely know the reason *why* something isn't working properly, please don't make up random guesses.

Comment: @DavidG :I believe you are wrong in this case.  You would get 401 or 403 if you were using the wrong user in the credentials.  This case you are using the wrong type of credentials.  The error is coming from a Windows Error indicating there is no Windows Credentials.  The Windows credentials are coming from client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName.

Comment: @jdweng No, an HTTP 415 has absolutely nothing to do with auth. It is almost certainly to do with the OP not sending the correct content-type or `SOAPAction` header, in this case possibly content type of `text/xml;charset=UTF-8`, it's been a while since I used SOAP so can't be sure.

Comment: Actually, the image provided shows the required headers.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved my issue by adding "application/soap+xml" inside the content

Comment: Told ya @jdweng...