# How to transform web server soap xml data into csv

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, c#-4.0

Can anyone help how to transform soap xml data into csv, I have gone through google but have not get anything related this topic, mostly topic I'm getting from google is how to transform xml file into csv, here I'm not required xml file transformation, I just need to know how to directly can call to soap web server and transfer its data into csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data using a SOAP client. After that you can just search for converting c# object or object list into CSV which should be easy to find.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6634420/6671523) post for SOAP client example.